# Regression with binary variables: should have 4 regression lines, only getting 1.

Tags: r, regression

I have two binary variables in my model, so I should get a plot with 4 regression lines on it, but I'm only getting 1 line. How do I plot all 4?

```
model<-lm(Pos.Percent~aum+long.short+Op.Der,data=new.reg)
        Pos.Percent long.short Op.Der    aum
[1,]       76.92          1      2      76.90
[2,]      100.00          1      2       8.10
[3,]       58.62          2      1      23.00
[4,]       60.00          1      1      15.00
[5,]       89.36          2      1      35.96
[6,]       82.50          2      1     263.49
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to get?

You say you want a plot, but you show no plots or commands to make plots. Your model has 2 categorical IVs plus an apparently continuous one.

What are the lines of data under your model statement?

Comment: All of the plots I did were not helpful, so I didn't post them. I used plot(model) to get summary plots, but it doesn't give me the actual regression lines. Since I have 2 categorical IVs, I should get 4 regression lines. I want to see the plot of all 4 regression lines at once.

Comment: I think this is off topic.  But this sort of thing is easiest with the ggplot2 package - it looks like you want library(ggplot2); ggplot(new.reg, aes(x=aum, y=Pos.Percent, colour=long.short, shape=Op.Der)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm")

Comment: or probably better (depending on how you want interactions dealt with) is ggplot(new.reg, aes(x=aum, y=Pos.Percent)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm") + facet_grid(long.short~Op.Der)

Comment: What are the modes of new.reg$long.short and new.reg$Op.Der?  Looks like you want them to be factors, but they are actually numeric.  And perhaps you want to model each level of their interaction.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185600/superposed-xyplot-panels-with-grouped-regression-lines

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very clear question.  But I am deducing that you want a separate regression line of Pos.Percent on aum for each combination of your two binary variables (by the way, this is not what your lm() command is estimating - but that's another issue).

One easy way to get a good plot for this is with the ggplot2 library in R:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(new.reg, aes(x=aum, y=Pos.Percent)) + 
  geom_point() +   
  geom_smooth(method="lm") + 
  facet_grid(long.short~Op.Der)
```